# How can I use PostGIS functions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

The query I'd like to run is:

```
SELECT zcta.geoid10, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_simplify(zcta.geom,500)) FROM zcta WHERE zcta.geoid10 = '90210'
```

However in the Rails console when I enter this:

```
testquery = "SELECT zcta.geoid10, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_simplify(zcta.geom,500)) FROM zcta WHERE zcta.geoid10 = '90210'"
Zcta.find_by_sql testquery
```

I get the following returned:

```
 => [#<Zcta >]
```

If I do a basic query asking for the result of any column I get the response I expect.  This only happens with PostGIS functions.  Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias the calculated column and you will get a method added to the returned objects.

```
Zcta.
  select("*, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_simplify(geom,500)) as my_geo").
  where(geoid10: '90210').each do |result|
    puts result.my_geo
  end
```

Comment: This worked but I dont really understand what's happening.  I'd like to assign the result of the query to a variable for use elsewhere.  I'm not really sure how to procede with this.  Why cant I have it just be somevariable = Zcta.select("ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as my_geo").where(geoid10: '90210') where somevariable would now be equal to the json string that comes out of the db?

Comment: ActiveRecord queries will always return ActiveRecord objects. You could do this ````somevariable = Zcta.select("ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as my_geo").where(geoid10: '90210').my_geo````

Comment: I tried that and I get a NoMethodError.  Undefined method for 'my_geo'

Comment: Just use the code in my answer, but instead of using puts, assign it to a variable.

Comment: I hate to be a pain but that was the first thing I tried and that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: I should be more clear.  The error is get when I then try to use the variable assigned in the do loop is "undefined local variable"